# Быстрая правка и конвертация ответов

Tags: дефект, инструменты-модератора

При переносе нескольких ответов в правки срабатывает период быстрой правки.

When converting multiple answers into edits, grase period is applied.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/793502/revisions